# Android Outgoing MMS get address

Tags: android, mms

I'm trying to get the recipient address of an outgoing MMS using this code.

```
private String getAddressNumber(String id) {
    String selectionAdd = new String("msg_id=" + id);
    String uriStr = MessageFormat.format("content://mms/{0}/addr", id);
    Uri uriAddress = Uri.parse(uriStr);
    Cursor cAdd = getContentResolver().query(uriAddress, null,
            selectionAdd, null, null);
    String name = null;
    if (cAdd.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String number = cAdd.getString(cAdd.getColumnIndex("address"));
            if (number != null) {
                try {
                    Long.parseLong(number.replace("-", ""));
                    name = number;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    if (name == null) {
                        name = number;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (cAdd.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cAdd != null) {
        cAdd.close();
    }
    return name;
}
```

But It's returning "insert-address-token" instead of the actual address.

Comment: Where is the id coming from?

Comment: From the _id property from a content://mms cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same problem, and after some exploration, figured it out as following solution, mms is special as its outgoing message does not reflect the sent time in DATE field, also, the address field will be "insert-address-token", and TYPE will be 151, to get recipient number, we need to combine several table's query together. :

```
private static String getAddressNumberOfRecipient(int threadId) {
    String selectionAdd = Telephony.Threads._ID + "=" + threadId;
    String uriStr = MessageFormat.format("content://mms-sms/conversations/{0}/recipients", threadId);
    Uri uriAddress = Uri.parse(uriStr);
    String[] columns = {Telephony.Threads.RECIPIENT_IDS};
    Cursor cAdd = context.getContentResolver().query(uriAddress, columns, selectionAdd, null, null);
    String name = null;
    if (cAdd.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            name = cAdd.getString(cAdd.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Threads.RECIPIENT_IDS));
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (cAdd.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cAdd != null) {
        cAdd.close();
    }

    return TextUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : getCanonicalRecipient(Integer.parseInt(name.split(" ")[0]));
}

private static String getCanonicalRecipient(int recipientId) {
    String selectionAdd = Telephony.CanonicalAddressesColumns._ID + "=" + recipientId;
    String uriStr = MessageFormat.format("content://mms-sms/canonical-address/{0}", recipientId);
    Uri uriAddress = Uri.parse(uriStr);
    String[] columns = {Telephony.CanonicalAddressesColumns.ADDRESS};
    Cursor cAdd = context.getContentResolver().query(uriAddress, columns, selectionAdd, null, null);
    String name = null;
    if (cAdd.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            name = cAdd.getString(cAdd.getColumnIndex(Telephony.CanonicalAddressesColumns.ADDRESS));
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (cAdd.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cAdd != null) {
        cAdd.close();
    }
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(name) ? "" : filterPhoneNumber(name);
}
```

Comment: I know it is a bit dated, but FYI you do not document the filterPhoneNumber method, but I assume it is simply a formatting function.

Comment: Thank you! It was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
private String getAddressNumber(String id) {
        String selectionAdd = new String("msg_id=" + id);
        String uriStr = MessageFormat.format("content://mms/{0}/addr", id);
        Uri uriAddress = Uri.parse(uriStr);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriAddress, null, selectionAdd, null, null);

        String phoneNum = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                if (number != null) {
                    boolean isNumberFormat = true;
                    try {
                        Long.parseLong(number.replace("-", ""));
                        phoneNum = number;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // ex) "insert-address-token"
//                        if (phoneNum == null) {
//                            phoneNum = number;
//                        }
                        isNumberFormat = false;
                    }
                    if (isNumberFormat)
                        break;
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return phoneNum;
    }
```